# Connected to LAN but no internet access

Tags: wireless-networking

So, I'm working at a company where my PC is connected to their network through a Cisco switch and router (wireless using access point), I'm able to receive emails through their email server and able to see the database and do basic data entry operations. Yet, when it comes to other website, I can't use the internet, when I try to ping google or other websites, I can't do so. However, using the same access point on my phone or laptop, I can access everything,

Is there a way by which I can access the internet?

What's the network setup from your perspective

Thank you all

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I'm supposed to be the I.T tech there, I'm trying to figure it out before I get the training ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS error. Can you do a tracert to say "cnn.com" should return IP address, this tells, you have connection to internet. Now try to put the ip address in a browser, if that works you are on the internet and dns is not working. Check the DNS entries for the wireless card. Set to either AutoDHCP AutoDNS or find solid DNS servers to input.

Comment: Well, I pinged 8.8.8.8 through the command line and I got destination unreachable, :\

Comment: I was thinking maybe the pc i'm using is set not to access the internet due to security purposes since all the transactions and company data (money related data) are accessed through that PC

Comment: tracert cnn.com (most servers wont reply to a ping)

Comment: if you cannot ping 8.8.8.8 then that pc has no access to the internet at all and your concern for it to be protected due to the nature of that pc is likely to be true.